# Collect data from UART based on multiple terminating characters

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, uart, esp8266

I am using an Arduino-like library on the WiFi module ESP8266. The code looks very much like Arduino.

I am collecting data from UART and placing them into a buffer. Currently, the terminating character is `'\n'`. In other words, the stream of incoming data from the UART is stored in a buffer `command_buffer` and the end of this incoming data is identified by the `'\n'`. Here is the relevant code;

```
void onDataCallback(Stream& stream, char arrivedChar, unsigned short availableCharsCount)
{
    if (arrivedChar == '\n') // Lets show data!
    {
        Serial.println("<New line received>");
        while (stream.available())
        {
            char cur = stream.read();
            charReceived++;
            Serial.print(cur);
            command_buffer[index] = cur;
            buf_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

`onDataCallback()` is a callback function that gets called when incoming data is received from the UART.

This is my problem. What if the terminating character is not a single character `'\n'`? What if it is made up of multiple binary characters like `<0xFF><0xFE><0xFA>`?

The Arduino-like libraries comes from the SMING framework.
https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get your characters one at a time, you'll have to remember a state: <kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95849de9974ad06f)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace
{
    const char uart_endl[] = "\xff\xfe\xfa";
    const size_t uart_endl_len = sizeof(uart_endl) - 1;
}

class DataReceiver
{
    const char* state;
    std::string buffer;
public:
    DataReceiver() : state(&uart_endl[0]) {}
    void onDataCallback(char arrivedChar)
    {
        buffer.push_back(arrivedChar);
        if (*state == arrivedChar)
        {
            state++;
            if (*state == '\0')
            {
                state = &uart_endl[0];
                buffer.erase(buffer.end() - uart_endl_len, buffer.end());
                std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            state = &uart_endl[0];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    DataReceiver buffer;
    buffer.onDataCallback('a');
    buffer.onDataCallback('b');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xff');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xfe');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xfa');
    buffer.onDataCallback('c');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xff');
    buffer.onDataCallback('d');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xff');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xfe');
    buffer.onDataCallback('e');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xff');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xfe');
    buffer.onDataCallback('\xfa');
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
ab
c�d��e
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Looks good. I was looking for an answer more suited for Arduino. I'm not sure there are equivalent functions for string functions `push_back`, `erase` and `clear`. Anyway, your answer has given me a good headstart. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If `std::string` is not entirely implemented, you can still use old-style char buffers. Good luck.